# How to allow pagebreaks within paragraphs and sentences

Tags: page-breaking

I have a problem with paragraphs jumping from one page to the next as a unit.  I want page breaks within paragraphs and within sentences, as the page length dictates. How do I do that?  Here is my LaTeX header, which I do not understand the first thing about. I want to reduce the number of pages. Also, are there bad things in my LaTeX header?

Thanks,  Jaime

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\setlength{\textwidth}{17 cm} \setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.8in} \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.1in}
\def\text#1{\;\;\hbox{#1}\;\;}    \def\Text#1{\quad\;\,\hbox{#1}\quad\;\,}
\def\eqalign#1{\begin{array}{lcr} #1 \end{array}}
\def\Tilde{\widetilde} \def\Hat{\widehat} 
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lastpage}%\hspace{-0.6mm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\mli}[1]{\mathit{#1}}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\cfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal complete and compilable example reproducing your problems. In particular, how are you setting your paragraphs?

Comment: for your main question it is impossible to say unless you provide an example. for the sub question about bad things, don't do `\def\text#1{\;\;\hbox{#1}\;\;} `  it would over-write the standard text command although there it does nothing as you load amsmath later. don't do `\def\eqalign#1{\begin{array}{lcr} #1 \end{array}}` (`array` is quite unsuited to setting multi-line equations, it is designed for matrices of value, not displays, use the amsmath alignments)  ...

Comment: ... your page size settings are a bit weird with widths in metric and heights in imperial, it would be better to use the `geometry` package and `\textheight` should be `\topskip` + an integer number of `\baselineskip` otherwise a page full of text can not fill the specified page dimensions.

Comment: There is nothing in the code shown that would prevent page breaks mid sentence. (unless your sentences are in `\text` or `\Text` )